# express-validator: isEmail() won't report if body.email doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, express-validator

Updated:

express-validator 7.0.1, node 16.16.0

1. follow the 1st example at https://express-validator.github.io/docs/guides/validation-chain
2. my initial code is like this

```
app.post('/newsletter',
  body("email")
    .isEmail()
    .withMessage('missing email'),
....
```

when running unit test with a body without email field, it says
Received: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'undefined' to data type int."

Why it cannot detect there's no email ?

3. then i changed the code like this

```
    app.post('/newsletter',
      body("email")
        .exists()
        .withMessage('missing')
        .isEmail()
        .withMessage('wrong email'),
    ....
```

it still says the same error msg from step 2.

What's the correct way to detect the email field is missing pls ?

---

Update from 7/11, i was able to make step 3 to work.
isEmail() is not good enough to handle all cases, it outputs general "invalid value", e.g. if no email field or a very long email. Such general error is not helpful to end user.

Comment: Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and show the full error stack

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your full code and I don't think I can help you, but in my opinion you can try this:

```js
app.post('/newsletter',
  body("email")
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('missing')
    .isEmail()
    .withMessage('wrong email'),
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my misunderstanding.

Initially i thought if the 1st validation is email, and if email validation fails, it'd stop there and return with error.

Actually it'll continue to the next validations and eventually goes into your error handler. In the error handler there's a errors.sort in my case, so a later error message was put in the beginning.

Basically it's a feature that express-validator won't stop at the 1st error.